How to get the SAML RelayState in Spring Boot Controller?
I could obtain the RelayState in Spring SAML 1 by accessing the SAMLCredential through the SecurityContext.
SAMLCredential saml = (SAMLCredential) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                 .getAuthentication().getCredentials();
String relay = saml.getRelayState();

How can I access the RelayState in a controller method using SAML2?

So after a lot of searching and trial and error, I came up with a way of doing it (although I really believe it should be simpler).
@Bean
Saml2AuthenticationRequestResolver authenticationRequestResolver(
        RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver registrations) {
    OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver authenticationRequests = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver(registrations);

    return new Saml2AuthenticationRequestResolver() {
        public <T extends AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest> T resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
            T post = authenticationRequests.resolve(request);
            
            String relayState = request.getParameter("RelayState");
            
            log.info("@Config - RelayState is {}", relayState);
            
            if (relayState != null)
            {
              HttpSession session = request.getSession();
              
              session.setAttribute("RelayState", relayState);
              
              log.info("@Config - RelayState saved to session");
            }
            
            return post;
        }
    };
}

Then in the controller method you would retrieve it as follows:
public String index(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String username = principal.getName();

    log.info("@Controller - Current Authenticated user: {}", username);
    
    model.addAttribute("username", username);
    
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    
    String relayState = (String) session.getAttribute("RelayState");
    
    log.info("@Controller - RelayState: {}", relayState);
    
    if(relayState != null) {
        session.removeAttribute("RelayState"); // prevent replay
        
        return "redirect:"+relayState;
    }
    
    return "index";
}

Basically, you can't directly get RelayState parameter directly from the HttpServletRequest in the controller because the initial SAML request is a POST that gets processed and validated, then a GET is generated and redirected to the controller. That second request does not include the request parameters from the first.
